# When click on an item in a tree, it makes the vertical scroll bar jump up

Tags: gwt, tree, uibinder, gwtp

Look at this simple code

```
 Tree testTree=new Tree(); 
 TreeItem testTreeItem=new TreeItem("test");
 TreeItem testTreeItem2=new TreeItem("test2");
 more TreeItem....

 testTree.addItem(testTreeItem1);
 testTree.addItem(testTreeItem2);
 ........
```

Now, resize your browser so that you can see the vertical scroll bar on the right hand-side. Now click on a tree item at the very bottom ex `testTreeItem10`, you will see the the vertical scroll bar jump up instead of staying in the current position.

This error also happens when using UiBinder

```
<g:Tree ui:field="myTree"> 
<g:TreeItem text="Item 1" /> 
<g:TreeItem text="Item 2" /> .....
</g:Tree>
```

Also, `addItem` of `Tree` got deprecated, so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is [SO] an official support forum for GWT? I didn't know that. I bet the others didn't too. If this is really a bug in GWT, you'd be better off reporting this issue to them, I think

Comment: seem this bug got since 2007, bt somehow Google didn't fix properly
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1606

Comment: Did you try the code suggested in the last comment? It is labeled as `//The below snnipet works fine`,

Comment: Yes, but it likes hacking code, it could break in the future

Comment: @Kiti GWT is open-source and awaiting your patches: http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html; StackOverflow can only get you workarounds, and if you refuse to use them, then there's a problem…

Comment: what u mean, i am not an expert in Java, i am just a 1 year experienced Gwtp coder.  How could i provide a patch to google, this bug got since 2007 but some how it's still there even I using the Gwt2.4 or newer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hacking code may work, but i am not sure it is the right way or elegant way to fix?

Could this hacking code break in the future?

By the way, just modify the Tree a bit:

```
    Tree testTree=new Tree(){

        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
            if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCLICK) {

                return;
            }

            if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
                //int s = scrollPanel.getVerticalScrollPosition();
                int scrollLeftInt = Window.getScrollLeft();
                int scrollTopInt = Window.getScrollTop();
                DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "position",
                        "fixed");
                super.onBrowserEvent(event);
                DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "position",
                        "static");

                //scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollPosition(s);
                Window.scrollTo(scrollLeftInt,scrollTopInt);
                return;
            }

            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solving this problem some time ago. This code did the trick for me.

```
private Tree gwtTree = new Tree(){
        @Override
        public void setFocus(boolean focus) {
            //Do not do anything!
        }
    };
```