# So GWT 2.6 fixed the bug "When clicking on an item in a tree, it makes the vertical scroll bar jump up" in GWT 2.5, did it?

Tags: gwt

Ok, about 8 months ago, I used Gwt 2.5 & got this problem.

The problem is that when I click on an item in a tree that is located inside a scrollpanel, it makes the vertical scroll bar jump up. See my question [When click on an item in a tree, it makes the vertical scroll bar jump up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131318/when-click-on-an-item-in-a-tree-it-makes-the-vertical-scroll-bar-jump-up)

A man suggested me a hacking code to fix that bug.

Tree testTree=new Tree(){

```
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCLICK) {

            return;
        }

        if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
            //int s = scrollPanel.getVerticalScrollPosition();
            int scrollLeftInt = Window.getScrollLeft();
            int scrollTopInt = Window.getScrollTop();
            DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "position",
                    "fixed");
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "position",
                    "static");

            //scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollPosition(s);
            Window.scrollTo(scrollLeftInt,scrollTopInt);
            return;
        }

        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    }

};
```

At that time, the hacking code seems to work ok.

Now recently I have just install the GWT2.6 & when clicking on the item it seems ok but it has just a little bit of shaking (only happened in IE not in CHrome). FOr a normal users this is not a big issue but for a very picky person they will not be very happy. So I removed the hacking code & it's seem to be ok in IE or Chrome.

So I assumed that Google fixed that bug.But i want to make sure if Google actually fixed that bug so that I can remove the hacking code completely.

Can anyone answer me if Google fixed that bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's marked as "Fixed" in the issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1467

(The issue you mentioned in your original question has been merged into this one.)

Comment: thank you, so this issue was fixed right? how did they fix? did they use the hacking code like i mentioned above?